# Djvu viewer in Chromebook?

Tags: chromebook, djvu

I was able to find only Djvu Viewer extension [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djvu-viewer-extension/jghccooedabolhnplggblcggcbplekbk/reviews?hl=en) but very bad ratings so there must be some better or even native solution. So

**How can I see DJVU files in Chromebook?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Evince filve viewer on your chromebook, like is [here](https://www.rollapp.com/app/evince).